# How can I measure/calculate the size a Document needs to render itself?

Tags: java, swing

I have a `javax.swing.text.Document` and I want to calculate the size of the bounding box that document needs to render itself.

Is that possible?

It is almost trivial for plain text (`height = line count * line height`, `width = max width over each line`) But how can I do this with RTF, HTML or any other document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code might give you some ideas:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class TextPanePerfectSize extends JFrame
{
    JTextField textField;
    JTextPane textPane;

    public TextPanePerfectSize()
    {
        textField = new JTextField(20);
        textField.setText("add text");
        getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH );
        textField.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try
                {
                    Document doc = textPane.getDocument();
                    doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), " " + textField.getText(), null);
                    textField.setText("");
                    Dimension d = textPane.getPreferredSize();
                    Rectangle r = textPane.modelToView( textPane.getDocument().getLength() );
                    d.height = r.y + r.height;
                    textPane.setPreferredSize( d );
                    getContentPane().validate();
//                  pack();
                }
                catch(Exception e2) {}
            }
        });

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hit Enter to Add Text to Text Pane");
        getContentPane().add(label);

        JPanel south = new JPanel();
        textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setText("Some text");
        textPane.setEditable( false );
//      textPane.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(120, 23) );

        south.add( textPane );
//      getContentPane().add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        getContentPane().add(textPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new TextPanePerfectSize();
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`Document`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html) interface is a [model](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/architecture/#separable) for a [text component](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html), so the [`Document`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html) doesn't really have a boundary; but the [`View`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/View.html) has a number of methods that "translate between the model and view coordinate systems." Depending on the goal, something there may help.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this to measure height for fixed widht.
http://java-sl.com/tip_text_height_measuring.html

The getPreferred will return you the width and height.