# How to make JTextPane wrapped in JScrollPane shrink to fit the text

Tags: java, swing, size, jscrollpane, jtextpane

I have a `JTextPane` with HTML text.

I used `GroupLayout` (using WindowBuilder).

I've set the minimum size of my `JFrame` to 800x600 so the user cannot make it smaller than that.

The app has a big scrolling `JPanel` the size of the entire window. The top part of the panel is taken up by a `JTextPane` wrapped in `JScrollPane`. I have disabled the scroll bars and sized the `JScrollPane` to make the entire text visible.

In group layout the `JScrollPane` is set to stay constant vertically, but size horizontally.

My issue is that when the user makes the window larger the `JScrollPane` also expands, but now there is a big white space left at the bottom of the text pane. Is there a way that I can make `JTextPane` shrink to fit its contents.

Also if you suggest a different layout, I would be willing to try it.

Answer (score 2):

I used this [`TextPanePerfectSize`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3318949/261156) example from @camickr to solve a similar problem. The example uses `validate()` and `pack()` to adjust to the preferred size. You might be able to adapt it to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SpringLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SpringLayout.html). It gives you far more control over the positioning of components. Look at the [SpringLayout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html) if you get stuck.

The trick in your case is to bind the bottom (south) of your JScrollPane to the top (north) of the screen.