# set size of the component on component resize event

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, componentlistener

I have my own class which derives from `JTextPane`. I want that the object of this class should divide his content on pages of given size. I am dividing on pages simply by drawing a line in proper place on `paintComponent` method.

Let's say that I write a letter and my `pane` has resized so that typed letter should on next page. I would like to resize my pane more to has the size of one more page. I know that I should write a `ComponentListener` and add some code in `componentResize` method but I can't explicity use `setSize` method because it generate another event and I will get exception.
Thus, how can I do that properly?

Comment: See also [`TextPanePerfectSize`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3318949/230513).

Comment: However this is not what I want...

Comment: If you post a working sample it will make life easier :). I did a small experiment and the result is that you can `setSize` in `KeyListener` and just do normal painting in the `paintComponent` method. This seems to be working.

Comment: @KDM: A `DocumentListener` might be more flexible.

Comment: @trashgod: Not sure when it will be invoked. I guess after the keypress/repaint etc. is done. Without looking at JDK source, I think KeyListener is a better bet.

Comment: May be it's better to define pagination like this http://java-sl.com/Pagination_In_JEditorPane.html

Comment: Wow, this pagination is pro :D However, is there any way to use it together with `HTMLDocument`?

Comment: Ok, I have it. This is a superb solution http://java-sl.com/JEditorPanePrinter.html Thanks to StanislavL